# Gaining Canadian citizenship through the Army?

Tags: canada, citizenship

http://www.forces.ca/en/page/applynow-100 says

> To apply to the Forces, you must: Be a Canadian Citizen.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/cit/grant/cfa.asp says

> This section is about granting citizenship to a person who is or was serving in or with the Canadian Armed Forces (CAF).

So... what's going on here? (note: I am a Canadian citizen for ten months now, it's not like I am counting, just curious)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, yes, you can [emphasis mine] !

According to [Defense Administrative Orders and Directives 5002-1, Enrolment](http://www.forces.gc.ca/en/about-policies-standards-defence-admin-orders-directives-5000/5002-1.page#qe)

> Citizenship
>
> 3.3 An applicant is required to be:
>
> a. Canadian citizen; or
>   b. a ***citizen of another country who has permanent resident status under the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act*** and:
>      i. undertakes to become a Canadian citizen immediately when eligible to do so;
>       ii. provides service that satisfies a special need; and
>       iii.whose enrolment, in the opinion of the Commander (Comd) Canadian Forces Recruiting Group (CFRG), would not prejudice the national interest.
>
> 3.4 An applicant who is both a Canadian citizen and a citizen of another country may be enrolled.

Comment: Wait a minute so the army website is ... not exactly truthful? I thought all those years while I was a PR that besides running for office and voting for office army was the third difference between citizen and PR. Mind. Blown.

Comment: Gee whiz; the government is being cagey? :-) Note that you have to be _special_ and the Comd has to let you join _his_ forces.

Comment: In the past, solely based on the CIC site, I was considering offering my services to the army as a software developer if no other route were available towards citizenship. And, if push comes to shove I am a *special* software developer.

Comment: You _are_ special :-) Service in the US armed forces is also a path to citizenship.